# Python name 'os' is not defined

Tags: python, import

I am trying to run this python module

```
from settings import PROJECT_ROOT

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':  'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME' : os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_name.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'sdfgtardyure34654356435'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver; added in v1.4
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'

############### PYSEC specific variables

# assumes this directory exists
DATA_DIR = "%s/pysec/data/" % PROJECT_ROOT
```

But whenever i try to run it by `F5` i get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\pysec-master\local_settings-example.py", line 11, in <module>
    'NAME' : os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_name.sqlite3'),
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

The module lives in the `C:\Python27\pysec-master` and i got pysec for [here](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec)

Do you know what must i do to run the module with success?

Comment: Do you `import os`? And `# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.`?!

Comment: I wrote `import os` on the top of the module.

Comment: +1 I don't know why but @jonsharpe must have said something really good!

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Just add:

```
import os
```

in the beginning, before:

```
from settings import PROJECT_ROOT
```

This will import the python's module **os**, which apparently is used later in the code of your module without being imported.

Comment: Hooray it works!!!!! Yep sucks being that beginner! thanks buddy!

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant You can click the check button on which answer you think is best(probably this one, but I can hope :) to accept it.

Comment: Excellent! just added `import os` to the settings.py and it worked

Comment: just added " import os " to the settings.py and it worked

Answer (score 36):

The problem is that you forgot to import os. Add this line of code:

```
import os
```

And everything should be fine.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I had a number of autokey python scripts that used `os` without importing it. They worked fine in Kubuntu 19.10 and earlier, but stopped working after upgrading to Kubuntu 20.04. `import os` fixed those scripts. Thank you!